# How to correctly set alignments when using OpenLayers and CSS grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

I'm trying to create a very basic CSS grid layout incorporating an OpenLayers map. The layout has a header, menubar, map and footer panels. The problem I get is when the OpenLayers map is added - the footer panel is hidden and requires scrolling down to access the footer contents. I want the entire page to fit in the window extents but I'm missing something ...

PS - I'm using Chrome browser as the target browser.

I was using a static HTML page to prototype the layout, but I could not understand why the layout is broken.
I then created the code on JSFiddle to put with this question. However, the JSFiddle works as I had hoped it would in the static HTML page.

Maybe I have been looking at this too long, but any help is appreciated. I've included two solutions to try to understand the problem. Firstly the JSFiddle link that demonstrates a working example of what I want.
Secondly is the static HTML code that doesn't work (notice how you need to scroll down to see the footer contents)

1 - JSFiddle code.
https://jsfiddle.net/w0s4xmc0/54334/

2- Static HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .map {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #container {
                height: 100%;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 1px;
                grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
                grid-template-rows: 40px auto 25px;
                grid-template-areas: 
                "h h"
                "m c"
                "m f"; 
                background-color: black;
                font-size: 20pt;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #header {
                grid-area: h;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #menu {
                grid-area: m;
                background-color: orange;
            }

            #content {
                grid-area: c;
                background-color: pink;
            }

            #footer {
                grid-area: f;
                background-color: purple;
                font-size: 10pt;
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
        
        <title>OpenLayers example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='header'>Header</div>
            <div id='menu'>Menu</div>
            <div id='content'>
              <div id="map" class="map">
                  <script>var map = new ol.Map({
                        target: 'map',
                        layers: [
                          new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                          })
                        ],
                        view: new ol.View({
                          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([153.0251, -27.4698]),
                          zoom: 8
                        })
                      });
                  </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Funnily enough the code snippet above worked fine in the stackoverflow editor ...

Comment: In your both links the footer is visible and accessible, can you please check the exact problem.

Comment: The map div is inheriting from the container div.  The zoom control and attributions height are huge, you need to set `font-size: initial;` in `.map`  Also `height: 100%;` in the map div is causing the problem even without running the script, remove it and it is correct until you run the script, but I can't see what OpenLayers is doing to pick up page height again.  @Just code the question says that, copy and paste the code, save as .html and open with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `.map` style to subtract the heights of the header, footer and gaps

```
        .map {
            height: calc(100% - 67px);
            width: 100%;
            font-size: initial;
        }
```

Stackoverflow uses an iframe where, as you observed, it seems to work differently.

Comment: That does indeed fix the problem, however, I don't understand the 67px. Was this value worked out via trial and error, or some other method? Thanks for the help - greatly appreciated.

Comment: from `grid-gap: 1px; grid-template-rows: 40px auto 25px;` 40 + 25 + 2*1